# react router 1@rc1 server side redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I need to redirect a page from another one on server side using the react-router.
The code I wrote it's working on client side, but not in the server render.
you can find the code here:

https://github.com/jurgob/iso-login/blob/e26af0152896a949435db62549027b2683276db7/src/shared/components/LoginPage.js

this is the redirect code inside */src/shared/components/LoginPage.js*:

```jsx
componentWillMount() {
    ...
    this.props.history.replaceState(null, '/home');
  }
```

**Note:**

If you look on https://github.com/jurgob/iso-login/blob/e26af0152896a949435db62549027b2683276db7/src/shared/routes.js

I did:

```jsx
function requireAuth(nextState, replaceState) {
  // replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/login');
}
...
<Route path="home" component={HomePage} onEnter={requireAuth} />
```

this code is working, but I would like to do the redirect inside the component

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in capacity in React Router to handle redirects within the component on the server side.

This is because `onEnter` hooks run within the context of `match`, so React Router can pick up on `replaceState` calls and notify the `match` callback of the requested transition. By the time `componentWillMount` runs, `match` has already invoked the callback.

You're most likely going to have to build some higher-level abstraction that instruments the `history.replaceState` call when rendering on the server, then takes the appropriate actions after `ReactDOM.renderToString` returns.

Answer (score 1):

A couple different ways to handle this:

1 - If you're okay with letting the redirect actually happen on the client side, you can do something like

```
history.push('/newPath/');
```

This is the solution I used, in order to not have two different kinds of redirects (on the client and on the server). In my case, I passed in a "context" props (only for the server side portion of the code, so my method looks more like

```
componentWillMount() {
  if (this.props.context) { // context only available on server side
    this.props.context.doLogout();
  }
  this.props.history.push('/newPath/');
}
```

2 - If you really want the server to do the redirect, then you have to pass down the response object from express or whichever framework you're using:

```
componentWillMount() {
  // you may have to this.props.history.push('/currentPath');
  this.props.res.redirect(302, '/newPath/');
}
```

Happy to elaborate if necessary - I spent some time banging on this and opted for the former solution (code simplicity over correctness, but whatever works for you).